# how to make the text vertical align the middle

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/PZ5AZ/

Please advise me what to do to make text Send Vertical align middle .also please advise that these problems not came in future what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you like to center the text inside the div vertically and perhaps horizontally you can try this

```
#container{
position:relative; 
width:200px; 
height:300px; 
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}   
#txt{
position:absolute; 
width:150px; 
height:50px; 
top:50%; left:50%; 
margin-top:-25px; /* 1/2 of height */
margin-left:-75px;/* 1/2 of width */
border:1px solid #FF0000; 
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="txt">My Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been previously said vertical alignment is not really supported on anything that isn't a table cell.

But if you are just trying to center a single line of text you could use `line-height`. If you set the `line-height` to the same as the `height` of the element and remove any padding then the text will display in the middle of the element, just as if it is vertically aligned.

So on your example the following would work (if you remove the default styles first):

```
line-height:28px;
height:28px;
padding:0px;
```

But if the text wraps to more than one line this solution won't work, the text will suddenly become very spaced.

For a more general solution it is best to use javascript to dynamically work out the padding required for the particular element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't vertically align text outside of tables so there are two options:

You play with the padding of the parent element to achieve the illusion of v-aligned text. As illustrated by Mr Long.

or

You make the parent element position:relative; and the child element absolute:

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='txt'>My Text</div>
</div>

#container{
position:relative;
} 

#txt{
position:absolute; left:0px; top:50%;
margin-top:10px; /* half the height of the text element */
}

/* hint: for scaling attributes use %'s */
```

I think the first option is the simplest in your case.

Good luck Bro!

W.

Comment: that should probably be `margin-top: -10px` (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this: padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Add this to clear default button padding in Mozilla:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
```